# Cassandra Alter keyspace for replication

Tags: cassandra

Seems to be I can't find the proper syntax for this.

Version 1.1.4 Snapshot
[cqlsh 2.2.0 | Cassandra unknown | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.32.0]

I can create a new keyspace with the following.

create keyspace something_interesting WITH strategy_class = 'NetworkTopologyStrategy' AND strategy_options:"99999" = 3 AND strategy_options:"44444" = 3 AND strategy_options:"66666" = 3;

However 
 ALTER KEYSPACE "something_interesting" WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', "66666":1,"44444":1};

Results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is the double quotes on the DC names, which should be single quotes. The following command works for me, albeit on a different CQL spec (3.1.1).

```
ALTER KEYSPACE something_interesting WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', '66666':1, '44444':2};
```

Using double quotes gives the error:

```
cqlsh> ALTER KEYSPACE something_interesting WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', "66666":1, "44444"2};
Bad Request: line 1:104 no viable alternative at input '44444'
```

Comment: Invalid syntax at line 1, char 45, it doesnt seem to like the curly bracket. its very odd